# iOS MKAnnotationView load deleted image

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a strange behavior when loading annotations in a map.
I have a custom annotation that loads different images according to a property.
During the development of the project i have changed one of this image (removed the resource from the project and added the new one)
When i debug the app with the simulator it work fine. loading the correct images.
On the device it still load the old image i removed. (the image is no longer in the project!)
I cleaned the device unistalling the app, and i still have the problem.

Here the code where i set the images in the annotations.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
static NSString *identifier = @"ParkingLocation";
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[ParkingLocation class]]) {

    ParkingLocation *parkLoc = (ParkingLocation *)annotation;
    if ([parkLoc.type isEqualToString:@"CHIUSO"])
    {
        parkLoc.imagePin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locator_parking"];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([parkLoc.type isEqualToString:@"PARCOMETRO"])
            parkLoc.imagePin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locator_strada"];
        else
            parkLoc.imagePin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locator_general"];
    }



    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [self.myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        annotationView.image = parkLoc.imagePin;

        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    } else {
        annotationView.image = parkLoc.imagePin;
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
}

return nil;
```

}

The image i changed in the project is named "locator_strada"
Anyone had the same behavior? Because i'm newbie about iOS and Objective-C , maybe i'm not considering some memory issue?
Thanks

Comment: are you see the red pin ?

Comment: please click the show in finder and check the image

Comment: The code looks ok.  On the device, is it showing some old "strada" image or do you mean it's showing a "parking" or "general" image where you expect a "strada" image?  Unlikely but make sure the resource file is named exactly "locator_strada.png" (all lowercase as device is case-sensitive).

Comment: Unrelated and not the cause of the problem but: The code is currently _setting_ `parkLoc.imagePin` in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.  Since this property is attached to the _annotation_ (and not the _view_), it's more logical to set it at the time you create the annotation objects (after you've set their `type`) and before you call `addAnnotation`.  This way, that property is set only once for each annotation.  Remember that the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method can be called multiple times for the same annotation.

Comment: @Deepesh i don't see red pin, but and old image i deleted, i searched in finder but is not present.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina thanks for the tips, i'll change my code as you describe. With the simulator it works, on real device i have the problem. On the iPhone i delete the App and installed it again. Maybe i have something more to clean?